# untar shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

i have a directory in which there are multiple tar files like

```
tweets10_1.tar
tweets10_2.tar
tweets10_8.tar
```

now i want to untar these files and keep them in a directory structure like

```
10_1
10_2
10_8
```

I have made a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
for string in `ls` ; do
  if [ $string == tweets10_*.tar*]; then
    length=${#string}
    folder=${string:6:$length-10}
    mkdir /mnt/filer01/round2/twitter/$folder
    tar -xvf $string -C /mnt/filer01/round2/twitter/$folder
  fi
done
```

this is giving me error `:3: [: missing ]` 
Please tell what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/mnt/filer01/round2/twitter"

for file in tweets*.tar
do
    NEWDIR=`echo $file | tr -d [a-zA-Z.]`
    mkdir $DIR/$NEWDIR
    tar -xvf $file -C $DIR/$NEWDIR
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The `[` command should be closed using a `]` *with a leading space*:

```
if [ $string == tweets10_*.tar* ]; then
```

Also, please don't do

```
for x in `ls`
```

Instead, use:

```
for x in *
```

Or, better:

```
for x in tweets10_*.tar
```

and skip the check altogether.

You can also extract out the `10_x` part more easily:

```
$ a=tweets10_8.tar; echo ${a//[a-z.]/}
10_8
```

Here, I'm removing the alphabets and the `.`.